# How do I reindex an array after using unset()?

Tags: php, arrays, unset

I'm having a little trouble with losing my array order after using `unset()`. This is the code I am using.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($my_array); $i++) {
  if ($my_array[$i] == $id) {
    unset($my_array[$i]);
  }
}
```

Assume that `$my_array` has 4 items and `$my_array[1]` is equal to `$id`. After I unset that, I loop on `$my_array` and I get an *Undefined Offset: 1* error. With `print_r($my_array)`, I get `$my_array[0]`, `$my_array[2]`, and `$my_array[3]`.

I understand perfectly why that's happening. Is there a way to re-index the array so that item 2 'drops' to item 1, and and the rest of the items respectively to the end of the array?

Something like `reindex($my_array)` would be sweet. I know I could run another for loop with a new array and transfer them manually, but a one step solution would be awesome. I just couldn't find anything anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values) to reindex the array.

Comment: dude you rock. Though I had tried that already. We'll just blame this one on it being after 2 am ;)

Thanks again

Comment: @Adam Well, it's past 7 am here :p I guess I'll go sleep too.

Comment: @Adam By the way, after the `unset`, you could iterate the now-one-element-short array with foreach. If you're reindexing because you're going to iterate with that for loop, it's unnecessary; just use `foreach` or `reset` and `next`.

Comment: Yeah I knew I could put in another couple of steps and do it that way, but array_values seems to be doing exactly what I needed. And yeah, 7am sounds like a nice stopping point :P

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered you can also do a

```
 array_splice($ar, 0, 0);
```

That does the re-indexing inplace, so you don't end up with a copy of the original array.